# Jupyter Notebook: "AttributeError: 'WebSocketProtocol13' object has no attribute 'is_closing'"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-console

Upon opening a ipynb file in my Jupyter application, no code will run and reserved words are not being highlighted. The hourglass icon in the window is always running.

[image]

In my Jupyter terminal, here's the message it throws me

```
File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 757, in _accept_connection
    yield open_result
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 553, in <lambda>
    self.stream.io_loop.add_future(result, lambda f: f.result())
```

Followed by:

```
      File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 758, in _run_callback
        ret = callback()
      File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 213, in nudge
        if self.ws_connection is None or self.ws_connection.is_closing():
    AttributeError: 'WebSocketProtocol13' object has no attribute 'is_closing'
```

Have no clue how to fix this - does a package need to be updated?